# Python - xlutils "filter.py" syntax error - print repr(self.name)

Tags: python, xlutils

I developing a script that will eventually use a pdfminer package to convert .pdfs to .txt files.  In preparing the the subject files for use, I am having to import copy from xlutils.copy

from xlutils.copy import copy, I run into a syntax error from one of the copy.py associated python files (*line 699* of xlutils\filter.py

```
def method(self,name,*args):
    if self.name:
        print repr(self.name),
    print "%s:%r"%(name,args)
```

the syntax error cursor points to the area of print repr(self.name) between the "r" and the left parenthesis.  I discovered **repr** is not defined until line 825 of the filter.py script.

What could be the exact cause of the syntax error and is their any way to correct the script such that filter.py does not trip up the xlutils.copy command?

Comment: are you using python3?

Comment: Yes, I am using python3.  Should this this operation be run from python 2 ( 2.7) instead?

Answer (score 0):

In python3, the print command  is significantly different. in particular you can't say `print x`. you have to say `print(x)`.  See https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Comment: Thanks, I corrected and it has allowed me to move forward...def  method(self,name,*args):
        if self.name:
            print (repr(self.name)),
        print ("%s:%r"%(name,args))  Also had to add parentheses to print arguments on several associate files/scripts.

Comment: great! btw, this change is backwards compatible to 2.7